# using span to hold image, not showing up unless its display is absolute

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem, I'm getting HTML Delivered from an API, and this is the HTML I receive:

```
<div class="card-summary__container">
<div class="card-summary__img"></div>
<h1 class="card-summary__title">@title</h1>
<h1 class="card-summary__alert">@number</h1>
<div class="card-summary__info">
    <p>TRENDING<p><span class="info-arrow-up"></span><span class="info-icon-up"></span>
</div>
```

The CSS I have applied is this:

```
.info-icon-up {
    background: url('../../../assets/img/svg/summary/trend-tick.svg') 50% no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-top: -4px;
}

.info-arrow-up {
    background: url('../../../assets/img/svg/summary/trend-arrow-up.svg') 50% no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-top: -4px;
}
```

And this is what I want to do:

[image: texthere *icon* *icon*]

So the two icons should be inline with the text, but unless I put there `position` as `absolute` the `img` doesn't show up, but if I do set the `position` as `absolute` then they won't position properly.

Is there something I'm doing wrong or something else I can do to get the desired result?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: First thing about CSS is there is no property like `display: absolute`. To find solution to your issue, include your full css code.

Comment: I clearly meant `position`, I just got the names mixed up, question has been fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `display:inline-block` to your span. Because `span` is `inline` element so it don't take height and width

Comment: Thank you this solved my issue, I will mark correct in 5 minutes

Comment: No problem @JuvenileSnow. Happy to help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

HI first of all i can see there is a mistake in your html.

```
<p>TRENDING<p><span class="info-arrow-up"></span><span class="info-icon-up"</span>
```

the last span must be closed like this

```
<span class="info-icon-up"></span>
```

And you can add `display:inline-block;`to you span so they will come inline.or you can put all the text and icons in span tag and inline them with `display:inline-block;` property.